# Win10 on a convertible without password: when do I have to click Login and when not when in Standby?

Tags: windows-10, standby, windows-10-v1607, automatic-logon

I have the following strange behaviour: on a tablet running Win10 x64, I have a user without a password, and selected that this user is logged on automatically. I don't have hybrid Standby enabled.

My problem is: when I got to energy save for only one or two minutes, and switch on the device, I get a picture to slide, and then logon.

However, if I wait for some minutes in standby, and enable my device, I get a single-colored screen, and when I swipe it, I have to click "logon" to get back to my desktop.

I wonder why the same action leads to different behaviours dependeing on the amount of time that has passed

I guess I am missing a new option in Windows update 1607, but which one?

Comment: Only thing I can think in one case your getting the locks screen, then the logon screen and the other the logon.  Can you confirm

Comment: In one case, after short time after energy safe, I get a image, and when I swipe the image, I am taken to the desktop directly. In the other case, I get a single-colored background, and when I swipe this, I get to the logon-screen. What's the difference between the two, and when do I get which, and why? Note that my user does not have a password set.

Comment: Honestly.  It sounds like a bug.  In both cases you should be getting the lock screen, at least on, 1607.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured out what is causing this behaviour, and as far as I can tell, this is clearly a bug caused by Microsoft, who don't have control about the complexity of their different settings anymore, as it seems.

As I said, my user doesn't have a password set , which means that some options in the `accounts-settings-dialog` (modern UI settings) aren't available. So the first thing I did was temporarily set a password for my user, which makes an option in the `Accounts -> Sign-in options` available that says "`Require sign-in: If you've been away, when should Windows require you to sign in again?`" which defaults to `15 minutes`. After setting this value to `never`, and then disabling the password (which also hides this settings option completely), everything worked as expected even when the user is in standby mode for a long time.

What is obviously happening is that, even if that option is invisible to users who don't have set a password and doesn't make any sense in that context, the corresponding setting behind in the registry is internally used anyway, and when the period of time has passed, the login-screen appears, even if login means to simply push a button, since no password is set at all.

That gives you a horrible impression of how good or bad Microsoft tests the different scenarios of their software. It took me some time to figure out, and I am happy that I finally found out what caused the behaviour I was experiencing, however, I am not really happy with what I figured out...